# How can I find parellel line on this image with opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

As shown in the picture, there are 2 parallel lines. 
How can I find the total number of parallel lines here with opencv-python?
[image]

Comment: Findcontours will give u an array as output which consist the coordinates of your contour. You can iterate each element of that array and finding slope of those 2 array elements. At the end, same slope means same angle thus parallel.

Comment: @kaankucuk you can move to Hough space, where the coordinates there are `r, Theta` then each parallel lines have the same theta.[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)

Answer (score -1):

You should use some math.
 1. Use OpenCV to detect lines. You need to remove short lines (noise).
 2. Calculate vector for each line, vi=(xi, yi)
 3. Say that v1=(x1,y1), v2=(x2,y2).

```
def is_parallel(v1, v2):
   x1, y1 = v1
   x2, y2 = v2
   thres = 3
   alpha = acos((x1*x2+y1*y2)/(sqrt(x1**2+y1**2)*sqrt(x2**2+y2**2)))
   if abs(0-alpha) < thres: return True
   if abs(180-alpha) < thres: return True 
   return False
```

4. Finetune thres to get the best result

Comment: So in second step how the way you ll find those x1,y1,....  What do you mean by saying short lines = noise? Everyone knows these steps the point is that how to achieve it!!!

Comment: You can easily detect lines by using cv2.HoughLinesP. It returns 2 end-points for each line. If you run the code at the end, you will see a lot of short lines in corners.
[https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html]